# Adding hierarchical encoding to a pointer-generator Text-Summarization model

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp

I'm working on text summarization, starting with the pointer-generator network described in the paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.04368.pdf, with a code release at: https://github.com/abisee/pointer-generator

I want to add hierarchical encoding to this network to be able to handle larger input documents for summarization. Right now, input documents are truncated at a length of 400 words because LSTMs have a keeping memory over very long inputs. We want to reweight the attention distribution considering sentence input.

The reweighting I am considering is from the paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.06023.pdf where the final distribution is

[image]

where "P_a^w(j) is the word-level attention weight at jth position of the source document, and s(j) is the ID of the sentence at jth word position, P_a^s(l)is the sentence-level attention weight for the lth sentence in the source, Nd is the number of words in the source document, and P_a(j) is the re-scaled attention at the jth word position"

The Pointer-Generator attention is calculated as

[image]

then

`softmax(e^t_ j)`

So I think I need to make another Pt-gen attention LSTM, feed the outputs through the same attention calculation with softmax as the words, and then at the end reweight as described in equation 1.

I have added a new bidirectionalLSTM under `def _add_encoder`. I am wondering how I should handle input into the sentence LSTM. The model needs to have some kind of indication of the position of the sentence and the words in it. How should I structure the sentences to be processed by the sentence LSTM?

```
def _add_encoder(self, encoder_inputs, seq_len):
    """Add a single-layer bidirectional LSTM encoder to the graph.

    Args:
      encoder_inputs: A tensor of shape [batch_size, <=max_enc_steps, emb_size].
      seq_len: Lengths of encoder_inputs (before padding). A tensor of shape [batch_size].

    Returns:
      encoder_outputs:
        A tensor of shape [batch_size, <=max_enc_steps, 2*hidden_dim]. It's 2*hidden_dim because it's the concatenation of the forwards and backwards states.
      fw_state, bw_state:
        Each are LSTMStateTuples of shape ([batch_size,hidden_dim],[batch_size,hidden_dim])
    """
    with tf.variable_scope('encoder'):
      cell_fw = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(self._hps.hidden_dim, initializer=self.rand_unif_init, state_is_tuple=True)
      cell_bw = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(self._hps.hidden_dim, initializer=self.rand_unif_init, state_is_tuple=True)
      (encoder_outputs, (fw_st, bw_st)) = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(cell_fw, cell_bw, encoder_inputs, dtype=tf.float32, sequence_length=seq_len, swap_memory=True)
      encoder_outputs = tf.concat(axis=2, values=encoder_outputs) # concatenate the forwards and backwards states


      sentence_encoder_inputs = ???
      sentence_lens = len(sentences_encoder_inputs)

      ### NEW CODE ###
      sentence_cell_fw = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(self._hps.hidden_dim, initializer=self.rand_unif_init, state_is_tuple=True)
      sentence_cell_bw = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(self._hps.hidden_dim, initializer=self.rand_unif_init, state_is_tuple=True)
      (sentence_encoder_outputs, (fw_st, bw_st)) = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(cell_fw, cell_bw, sentence_encoder_inputs, dtype=tf.float32, sequence_length=sentence_lens, swap_memory=True)
      sentence_encoder_outputs = tf.concat(axis=2, values=sentence_encoder_outputs) # concatenate the forwards and backwards states


    return encoder_outputs, sentence_encoder_outputs, fw_st, bw_st
```

Comment: Did you solved it ?